# find_all_by_{attribute} doesn't work for activerecord 4.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm using find_all_by to get the returned array from active record, and this feature works well for Rails(4.0.0)

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.0)
2.0.0-p353 :001 > Subscription.find_all_by_id 123
=> []
```

But when I changed it to Rails(4.1.5), find_all_by doesn't work, and throw undefined method error

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.5)
2.0.0-p481 :001 > Subscription.find_all_by_id 123
NoMethodError: undefined method `find_all_by_id' for #<Class:0x00000004d71b68>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any ideas to fix it or work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
Subscription.where(id: "123").to_a
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. 2.0.0-p481 :010 > Subscription.find(id: 123).to_a

Comment: Edited. Are you looking for a String or Integer?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has been trying to get `find_all_by` to work and have had no success, `find_all_by` has been deprecated and removed from rails.

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17357